# Mongo equivalent of `select distinct(name) from employee where age = "25"`

Tags: php, mongodb

I need help with finding distinct values but I also need to give a filter condition.
I have managed the distinct in this fashion :

```
$unique = $db->command(array("distinct" => "employee", "key" => "name"));
```

How do I add the "where age = "25" " clause to this?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`distinct()` in the MongoDB shell, and the `distinct` command both take a `query` argument which is used to filter the set of records to consider when determining distinct key values. In your example, you could do:

```
db.employee.distinct("name", {"age": 25})
```

in the MongoDB shell, or:

```
$db->command(array("distinct" => "employee",
                   "key" => "name",
                   "query" => array("age" => 25)))
```

in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. is this available in mongodb documentation?

Comment: Sort of -- there is a complete list of commands at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/List+of+Database+Commands which lists the `distinct` command with `collection`, `key`, and `query` arguments.